# Get the return value of a hook defined in a module?

Tags: 7, hooks

Is there a way to get the return value of a hook defined in a particular module for eg:

```
$views_theme_hook = module_invoke('views', 'theme');
```

By using `module_invoke` function, I got an array of themes declared in views module. Is this proper way of doing it?

But this function needs arguments for some other hooks for eg: `hook_tokens`.

How could I get the result for `hook_tokens` and other similar hooks requiring arguments?

Comment: There is only one way to do it. You should pass these arguments.

Comment: How can I get the arguments for all the hooks?

Comment: There is no universal way to do it. You should prepare data. For example - load node by nid and use it as data.

Comment: @alliswell It's not likely you would need to, but PHP has [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) if you're sure that's what you need to do. It would not be an easy job to come up with a pattern that would identify all possible Drupal hook implementations, though. You'd probably need to rely on well-documented code and string matching. There's definitely a better way to solve whatever problem you need to get over

Comment: Yes you are right. At last it was a pure PHP answer for a drupal question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module_invoke()` is a very simple function:

```
function module_invoke($module, $hook) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $module and $hook from the arguments.
  unset($args[0], $args[1]);
  if (module_hook($module, $hook)) {
    return call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $hook, $args);
  }
}
```

As you can see, it passes the arguments straight through to the hook function by way of `call_user_func_array()`.

So, you just need to pass the extra arguments with the call to `module_invoke()`. For example, to invoke `views_block_view()` with a specific block delta, you would use:

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'some_block_delta');
```

Comment: I think PHP reflection is the proper way to do it. I found a function drupal_help_arg() which builds arguments for invoking hook_help. I thought that there might be other functions to build argument like this.Any way I will proceed with reflection. Thank you :)

Comment: @alliswell There is not need to use reflection; just look at the documentation for the hook you are using.

Comment: are you suggesting to build the arguments by looking into the documents of the hook? Actually I need the return value of certain hooks which doesnot alter things but create drupal elements for eg: hook_node_info, hook_entity_info. these hooks don't require arguments but hooks like hook_theme require arguments.

Comment: I don't know how you'd do that programatically, I think you'll be looking in the files manually if that's what you need to know